# Iterating over lines in a file yields wrong number of lines

Tags: python

I am slowly becoming more familiar with Python, but have hit a major roadblock in what I thought would be a simple script.

Programmable infrared remotes store their infrared codes in a file format called ProntoEdit HEX. This is essentially a long file, where each line in the file represents the data for a particular IR code. The data is represented in hexadecimal numbers, with a space between each. I have edited the file, so that each line contains only hex numbers, with a space between each (no 0x preceding the hex numbers). There are 64 hexadecimal numbers per line. They are in pairs, so each line contains 32 pairs. In order to convert the data into a simple binary string, you divide the second number of each pair by the first, and depending on the ratio, it is either a 1 or a 0.

Hopefully you've followed all that. I have managed to write a script in Python to automate this for me, as there are 768 lines in the file I'm starting with. The script appears to be working, but for some reason, it only does half of the file, and then stops. It also seems to be skipping the first line of the file. I have checked by hand, and it is correctly "decoding" from the second line until exactly halfway through the file, at line 384. I am at a loss as to why this is happening.

Here is the (relatively) simple script:

```
rawcode = open(r"stripped.txt", "r")
outputfile = open(r"output_codes.txt", "w")
currentline = 0
for lines in rawcode:
    output = [] #empty list for output
    line = rawcode.readline()
    splitline = line.split(" ") #turn the line into a list
    splitline.remove('\n')

    y = 0
    for x in list(range(32)): #go through each pair in the line
        num1 = int(splitline[y], 16)
        num2 = int(splitline[y+1], 16)
        if (num2 / num1) == 3:
            output.append("0")
        elif (num2 / num1) == 7:
            output.append("1")
        y += 2

    print(output)
    outstring = ''.join(output)
    outputfile.write(outstring)
    outputfile.write("\n")
    currentline += 1
    print(currentline)

outputfile.flush()
outputfile.close()
rawcode.close()
```

Also, here is a link to the input file, and the output file that I'm getting.

[stripped.txt](http://pastebin.com/hAvBabWZ)

[output.txt](http://pastebin.com/mERzZg7N)

If anyone has experience working with file in this manner, your help is greatly appreciated! I am really not familiar with the intricacies of Python -- as you can probably tell, I come from a C background, and am still struggling with the different philosophies of the two languages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're doing a double-read here:

```
for lines in rawcode:
    output = [] #empty list for output
    line = rawcode.readline()
```

It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish, since your description of the process makes no sense. (It may well be accurate, but it still makes no sense: divide and then round to 1 or 0?)

Okay, this seems to work:

```
#!python3

with open('stripped.txt') as infile, open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue

        hexnums = [int(hn, 16) for hn in line.split()]
        for num1, num2 in zip(hexnums[0::2], hexnums[1::2]):
            digit = '0' if num2 // num1 == 3 else '1'
            outfile.write(digit)
        outfile.write('\n')
```

I get 768 lines of output, just like the input, with the first bunch being:

```
01000000000000010100011111111111
01000100000000010100001111111111
01000010000000010100010111111111
01000110000000010100000111111111
01000001000000010100011011111111
01000101000000010100001011111111
01000011000000010100010011111111
01000111000000010100000011111111
01000000100000010100011101111111
01000100100000010100001101111111
01000010100000010100010101111111
01000110100000010100000101111111
01000001100000010100011001111111
01000101100000010100001001111111
01000011100000010100010001111111
01000111100000010100000001111111
01000000010000010100011110111111
01000100010000010100001110111111
01000010010000010100010110111111
01000110010000010100000110111111
```

Comment: No, not dividing and then rounding. Depending on the result of the division (which will either be 3 or 7), this then decodes as either a 1 or a 0. It's the ratio between each pair that determines if it's a 1 or a 0. I'm going to try and fix the double read, and see where that gets me.

Comment: Your code also works, but by simply changing my code to remove the double-read, it also works!
Thank you SO much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the call to readline(). Your essentially reading every other line. Use the lines var from the iterator and you should get every line.

When you call readline() you're pulling the next line and ignoring the one that you're already getting from lines